# Rails store to different tables within the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Livestock and History

a livestock has many histories and history belongs to livestock

This is the create method inside the LivestockController

```rb
  # POST /livestocks
  # POST /livestocks.json
  def create
    @livestock = Livestock.new(livestock_params.permit!)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @livestock.save
          format.html { redirect_to @livestock }
          flash[:success] = "Livestock was successfully created"
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @livestock }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @livestock.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I wanted to create a record in the histories table with

```rb
history = History.new(livestock_id: @livestock.id, event: "Purchased", event_date: @livestock.purchase_date, image: @livestock.image)
history.save!
```

inside the create method

How can I do it? I can't put it in the create method because it says

`Validation failed: Livestock must exist`

apparently @livestock has not yet have the id attribute

**Edit:**
it still raises the same exception when I put it after
 `if @livestock.save`

However I found a work around by using the session variable. Since it is redirected to the show page, I created the following inside the create method

`session[:created] = "created"`

And in my show method

```rb
  # GET /livestocks/1
  # GET /livestocks/1.json
  def show
    if session[:created] == "created"
      history = History.new(livestock_id: params[:id], event: "Purchased", event_date: @livestock.purchase_date, image: @livestock.image)
      history.save!
      session.delete(:created)
    end
  end
```

Now I am wondering what are consequences if I use this approach.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Livestock record is created when you call `save` (and there is no validation error). So one option is to create the history inside this `if` condition:

```
if @livestock.save
```

Another option is to use `after_create` callback in the `livestock` model that will create a `history` object right after creating `livestock`. You have to be careful because the callback might be called when you do not need it (i.e. when importing data).

The last option is to create a separate service object that will create `livestock` and all other required objects. That's probably the best approach, but it will require more customized code.

**Update**

Please also make sure to move if/else block outside the `respond_to` block:

```
if @livestock.save
  # create history object here

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @livestock }
    flash[:success] = "Livestock was successfully created"
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @livestock}
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @livestock.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: wow can't believe this makes everything different. Thank you.